# android custom toasts

Tags: android, toast

I was able to make custom toast using this code

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.custom_toast));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_tv);
    text.setText("Hello! This is a custom toast!");

    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());       
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
```

However, since I do not understand the purpose of `LayoutInflater`, I modified the code to this...

```
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setView(findViewById(R.id.custom_toast));
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
```

And I get RuntimeException saying "setView must have been called"..

- Why can't I just assign the view to toast without using `LayoutInflater`?
- What is the purpose of `LayoutInflater` in general so that I can apply this experience to other custom views?

**Edit:**
I am using these codes in `onListItemClick()` interface method.. after the content is set..

Comment: I think a good question would be "what does a LayoutInflater internally do"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question have your answer, every custom view should inflate first, that's the reason you got an error with your modified code.

Comment: if I am assigning a Button to java from xml, findViewById works fine... I do not use any inflater there.. Why use it here? Is it because The `setContentView` is already used once and any further content changes should be from **layout inflating**?

Comment: because the toast is custom & the button is not(android default). with the xml you can assign/change some property of the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

This is what you also did it,and it is complete right code,you have your answer,
For assign custom view we have to use infalte the custom view first .

Thank you