# Make minimal message info in my application

Tags: android, dialog

How I can generate this dialog (on sreenshot) from my application, with other text, eg: "Please insert SD Card"? I know that is Toast, AlertDialog, but it is different from the dialog on screenshot.

[image: Minimal dialog]

I will write appliction only for me on Android 4.1.

Comment: I have posted the answer, but next time at least try google-ing or searching on stackoverflow for similar topics since there are thousands of them in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom layouts for your Toast or AlertDialog. They can look like anything you want(almost)

Here are some links for custom toast.

[Custom toast in android : a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-in-android-a-simple-example)

[android custom toasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089298/android-custom-toasts)

Comment: Thank You for answer. I learn programming on Android about 2 weeks. I don't know that Toast or AlertDialog can be customize. I found this web: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Its good you found that. Yes they can be customized in various ways, you'll see...Good Luck!